# Asp WebApi: Prettify ActionResult JSON output

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm working on REST service based on ASP.NET Core Web API and want to add a parameter 'prettify' to my endpoint so that response json will be formatted with indentation and readable in web browser.

My question - how can I change JSON formatting per controller method in ASP.WEB API Core application?

Appreciate you help.

Comment: Create an action filter that can be used on which ever action you want to add that functionality. I had achieved the same in web api (not core) using a delegating handler. that would inspect the request and update the json formatter indent based on prettify=true query parameter in the URL

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Thank to @Nkosi comment, I've found the solution. Below is a code of the action filter that looks for 'prettify' parameter and adds indentation to output JSON. If the parameter omitted, indentation is also added.

```
public class OutputFormatActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var actionResult = context.Result as ObjectResult;
        if (actionResult == null) return;

        var paramObj = context.HttpContext.Request.Query["prettify"];
        var isPrettify = string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramObj) || bool.Parse(paramObj);

        if (!isPrettify) return;

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };

        actionResult.Formatters.Add(new JsonOutputFormatter(settings, ArrayPool<char>.Shared));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an action filter that can be used on which ever action you want to add that functionality. I had achieved the same in Asp.Net Web API 2 (not core) using a `DelegatingHandler` that would inspect the request and update the json formatter's indent based on `prettify=true` query parameter in the URL

Here is how it was done with the delegating handler

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom handler to allow pretty print json results.
/// </summary>
public class PrettyPrintJsonHandler : DelegatingHandler {
    const string prettyPrintConstant = "pretty";
    MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;charset=utf-8");
    private System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration httpConfig;
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <seealso cref="PrettyPrintJsonHandler"/> class with an HTTP Configuration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config"></param>
    public PrettyPrintJsonHandler(System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration config) {
        this.httpConfig = config;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var canPrettyPrint = checkQuery(request.RequestUri.Query);
        var jsonFormatter = httpConfig.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        jsonFormatter.Indent = canPrettyPrint;

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (canPrettyPrint && response.Content != null) {
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = contentType;
        }

        return response;
    }

    private bool checkQuery(string queryString) {
        var canPrettyPrint = false;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryString)) {
            var prettyPrint = QueryString.Parse(queryString)[prettyPrintConstant];
            canPrettyPrint = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prettyPrint) && Boolean.TryParse(prettyPrint, out canPrettyPrint) && canPrettyPrint;
        }
        return canPrettyPrint;
    }
}
```

which was added as a global message handler during setup.

The same concept could be applied to an action filter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Valentine's answer, and for Newtonsoft Json.NET (and .NET Core), I came up with this action filter implementation, which formats the response for content values except where the content value type is string:

```
public class OutputFormatActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var objectResult = context.Result as ObjectResult;
        if (objectResult?.Value == null) return;
        if (objectResult.Value is string) return; // ignore string values - it would add extra quotes around the string in the response

        var jsonFormatter = new NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter(
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                // set custom json settings here
            },
            ArrayPool<char>.Shared,
            new MvcOptions(),
            new MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions()
        );

        objectResult.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatter);
    }
}
```

Register the action filter in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` to apply it to all MVC/Web API controllers:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new OutputFormatActionFilter());
});
```