# AspNet Core - input/output JSON serialization settings at Controller Level

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json-serialization

My application requires the (almost default) JSON serialization settings:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
                options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
            });
```

For one controller only, I need to use a different naming strategy for both input (where I use model binding with `[FromBody] myComplexObject` and output with

```
options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```

My question is virtually identical to [Web API: Configure JSON serializer settings on action or controller level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499041/web-api-configure-json-serializer-settings-on-action-or-controller-level) with the exception that I'm asking for AspNet Core 2.2+, in which `IControllerConfiguration` is no longer existent.

The Core 2.1+ equivalent question has a response here: [Configure input/output formatters on controllers with ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769415/configure-input-output-formatters-on-controllers-with-asp-net-core-2-1/52193035#52193035)

The answers there appear slightly fragmented or incomplete - it's hard to imagine that there is no easier way to achieve this.
Would anyone have an idea on how to use a DefaultContractResolver for all input and output within a single controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer you link works well enough, but you can extend it further by wrapping it in an attribute that you can apply to any action or controller. For example:

```
public class JsonConfigFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
            };

            var jsonFormatter = new JsonOutputFormatter(
                serializerSettings, 
                ArrayPool<char>.Shared);

            objectResult.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatter);
        }

        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

And just add it to action methods or controllers:

```
[JsonConfigFilter]
public ActionResult<Foo> SomeAction()
{
    return new Foo
    {
        Bar = "hello"
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidG - that won't take care of the input formatter for `[FromBody] object` though, or would it? I thought that is the missing piece in the original question as well.

Comment: Hmm you may be right. In that case you may be better off with a custom model binder.

Comment: @ExternalUse Have you tried the input side of this? I don't think the JSON input formatter cares too much about the case inside of the request, so it should work with `SomeProperty` and `someProperty` without any changes. It also works with `SOMePRoperTY` - if you provide multiple variations in the JSON the last one wins.

Comment: The answer provided works fine (thank you!); it is worth making a note of @KirkLarkin 's  comment above. The input filter does indeed appear to ignore the casing.

Comment: I expect `objectResult.Formatters` to include mvc OutputFormatters added in mvc configuration, but it's always empty. `IControllerConfiguration.Initialize` had `HttpControllerSettings settings` parameter which has all the mvc outputformatters added. That's a bit different.

Comment: .NET Core version of the action filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73866496/379279

Comment: @xhafan This is already a .NET Core version. Your code just implements the lower-level interface.

Comment: @DavidG ok, I remember now - I needed something for all controllers, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

For Global Setting in Startup.cs, having installed Newtonsoft.json, you will have this

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

For Individual Controller, you can override the global setting below

```
 public JsonResult GetStates()
    {
        var model = new List<StateObject>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            var schedule = _settingsService.GetStates().ToList();
            return Json(new SelectList(schedule, "StateCode", "Name"), new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
        }
        else
            return Json(new SelectList(model, "StateCode", "Name"), new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
    }
```

Let me know if this solves your problem, or you need further Assitance.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel, that takes care of the Output problem but not about ModelBinding on a POST with a `[FromBody] object` parameter. The global setting in the Startup class is not an option since for most other controllers, the default setting is correct. Only one controller requires a `DefaultContractResolver`

Comment: This kind of solved the issue.
But for each request $id is getting appended. For example, 
for first request $id starts with 1, but for all subsequent requests $id starts with 27,55... 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832635/is-there-a-way-to-reset-id-in-json-response-for-each-http-request

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Just override `Json()` in your controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public override JsonResult Json(object data)
    {
        return base.Json(data, new JsonSerializerSettings {
            // set whataever options you want
        });
    }
}
```