# Is there a way to reset $id in JSON response for each HTTP Request? JsonSerializerSettings = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

XYZController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] T inputContext)
{
       var outputContext = Process(inputContext);
       return StatusCode(200, outputContext );
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                UpdateJsonSettings.ConfigureJsonFormatter(options.SerializerSettings);
            });
}
```

UpdateJsonSettings.cs

```
internal static void ConfigureJsonFormatter(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
{
       settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
       settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
       settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
}
```

HttpResponse for XYZ Controller Try 1:

{
  "$id": "1",
  "bill": {
    "$id": "2",
    "type": "TYPE1",

HttpResponse for XYZ Controller Try 2: -- does not start with $id 1

{
  **"$id": "28",** <--- NOT SURE WHY ON THE SECOND REQUEST $ID starts with 28 :(  -->
  "bill": {
    **"$id": "29"**,
    "type": "TYPE1",

HttpResponse for XYZ Controller Try 3: -- does not start with $id 1

{
  **"$id": "55",** <--- NOT SURE WHY ON THE SECOND REQUEST $ID starts with 55 :(  -->
  "bill": {
    **"$id": "56"**,
    "type": "TYPE1",

I am using Newtonsoft.Json (11.0.2)

Comment: Could you show how do you get the response(your web api code to reproduce)?

Comment: I've added controller information.

Comment: This cannot be produced using the example code / json settings provided. `$id` is reset for me on each `JsonConvert.Serialize` call. You need to provide more information, such as what the input and output models look like? What does the `Process` method roughly do?

Comment: I have another controller which is just returning health check. 

[HttpGet]
  public async Task<ActionResult> GetHealth()
        {
            dynamic healthStatus = true;
            return Ok(healthStatus);
        }
 }
which is also returning referenced $id from the last call.

Comment: [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HealthController : ControllerBase
 {
} 

Controller registration signature

Comment: I have also tried updating latest Newtonsoft package.

Comment: Not sure why the question was downvoted? I have spent days on solving this one and is a legit one IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned this the hard way!

Issue was in StatusCode method, it was returning ObjectResult. After changing method signature to IActionResult and returning JsonResult, it is working fine. Also, API performance is improved.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] T inputContext)
{
       var outputContext = Process(inputContext);
       var jsonResult = new JsonResult(outputContext);
       jsonResult.StatusCode = 200;
       return jsonResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I opened a [thread on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20672) to discuss this.

Basically, the problem with `StatusCode` caching the `$id` values is because [this line of code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.cs#L26).

For performance reasons, `NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter` chose to cache `JsonSerializer` used to serialize objects. This will also cache the [`DefaultReferenceResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/7217c484e9705b5e76585c8b7fcd489c8e021c23/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultReferenceResolver.cs) and its inner counter.

As I said in the Github issue, there is a way to workaround this for each request using a custom [`IReferenceResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_ReferenceResolverProvider.htm). But, it would be a long way to work out for each request since the resolver is also cached in a singleton / static context.